# Can I use Steam Family Sharing to play an Origin or Ubisoft game?

Tags: steam, origin, ubisoft-connect, steam-family-sharing

Can I Use Steam Family Sharing to play an Origin or Ubisoft game if I don't own it on Steam but I do own it on Origin or on Ubisoft Connect/Uplay?

I am asking this to see if I can get the games' achievements on Steam while I own the game on the other store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Steam Family Sharing is only useful for games on Steam, and even then only those where the publishers themselves decide to support it (more likely an opt-out than opt-in).

SFS cannot allow you to share an app you don't own on Steam, or an app that isn't on Steam, or an app that's on Steam but doesn't allow Steam Family Sharing.

You may have gotten confused with Steam Link, which can be used to remotely play games and isn't limited to just Steam.

Comment: thanks, so there is no point in buying a game that activates on origin if you plan to eventually buy it on steam

Comment: fortunately I did not get it confused with steam-link as I haven't used it, I was just curious as most games on Ubisoft are activated separately on ubi-connect even if you bought them on steam, meaning you can close steam and use ubi-connect directly to launch and play the game, so I was wondering if I owned it on the third party store would I be able to use SFS to play it via steam solely for the being able to get the steam achievements.

Comment: Only point I can think of is if the saves can be shared and you want to get a headstart, but of course that could mean skipping past some Steam achievements in the early game (though they would likely be easy ones then).

Comment: right, so it's practically a bust anyway, and as for achievements, the EA games usually have some of those linear non-challenging achievements as far as I have seen, and in case of BF3 , the web-based game launcher does not help at all, it breaks the games link with steam so I have not been able to get a single achievement on steam while playing BF3

Comment: thanks again for the answer